# Codeigniter Fatal error: Interface 'App\Model\ModeInterface' not found

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've doing my website in windows. Then I tried to move my project to ubuntu server. I've clone my repository to server directory, but when I tried to access my project, it shows error message  `Interface 'App\Model\ModeInterface' not found in var/www/html/my-project/application/models/TeacherModel.php on line 5`.

Here's the code in `TeacherModel`

```
<?php if (! defined('BASEPATH')) {
   exit('No direct script access allowed');
 }

 class TeacherModel extends CI_Model implements App\Model\ModeInterface
 {
```

When I check, file `ModeInterface` refer to folder `src\Model` in project folder structure.

Here's the code in `ModeInterface.php`

```
<?php

 namespace App\Model;

 interface ModeInterface {
    /**
    * Fetches the row of database by primary key
    *
    * @param mixed|array|null $id One primary key or an array of primary keys
    *
    * @return array|object|null The resulting row of data, or null.
    */
    public function find($id);
 }
```

I've tried add `namespace App\Model` in `TeacherModel`, but it doesn't work because the error code is same.

Do you know how to fix this ?

Thank you

Comment: Make sure the file is named `ModeInterface.php` and not `Modeinterface.php` or `modeinterface.php` or `modeInterface.php`. On Linux, name will be case sensitive; on Windows, it won't be.

Comment: Hi @ceejayoz, it's same format  `ModeInterface.php`